# Is there an SWT or JFace dialog for selecting both directories and files?

Tags: java, swt, jface

`FileDialog` only lets me select files; `DirectoryDialog` only directories. I want users to be able to select either.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience (using Ubuntu with Unity) when I want to choose a folder or a file, I use `FileDialog`. marking a folder and pressing OK, will return the selected folder, and will not open it.

[image]

Comment: I think I tried that on Ubuntu with Gnome 2 earlier today, and it didn't work. Will retest after the weekend.